# Making a yet-to-become carousel responsive

Tags: html, css

My problem seems simple but as a beginner I can't figure it out. I wrote the following html:

```
<div class="discs container">
    <ul>
        <li><div class="arrowleft"><a href="#" ></a></div></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" ></a></li>
        <li><div class="arrowright"><a href="#" ></a></div></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and css:

```
.container {width: 960px; margin: 0 auto;}
.discs {
padding: 16px 0 16px 0;
border-bottom: 1px solid transparent;
outline: 1px solid #333333;
}

.discs ul li div.arrowleft a, .discs ul li div.arrowright a { background:        url("../i/navelem.png") no-repeat; width: 17px ; height: 37px;}
.discs ul li div.arrowleft a {background-position: 0 -80px;  } .discs ul li div.arrowright a {background-position: -20px -80px;}

.discs ul {
margin: 0;
}
.discs ul li {
display: inline-block;
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
border-radius: 1px;
padding: 2px;
margin: 0 4px;
}

.discs ul li:first-child, .discs ul li:last-child {border: none; padding: 12px; position: relative; vertical-align: 120%;margin: 0;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(2) {margin-left: 0;} .discs ul li:nth-child(8) {margin-right: 0;
}
.discs ul li a  {display: block; background: url(../i/sheetdiscs.png) no-repeat 0 0;    height: 100px; width: 110px;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(3) a {background-position: -126px 0;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(4) a {background-position: -252px 0;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(5) a {background-position: -378px 0;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(6) a {background-position: -252px 0;}
.discs ul li:nth-child(7) a {background-position: -126px 0;}
```

When I scale the web page, it all jumps around and I can't really figure how to make it stay in one piece and be responsive. I tried using em's on sizes and margins but it doesn't help. How do I make it responsive?

EDIT: Here's a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/LtwNw/

Comment: could you post a fiddle reproducing the issue?

Comment: What do you mean "scale the web page"?  Do you mean zoom the screen, or change the size of the container?

Comment: https://github.com/filamentgroup/responsive-carousel

Comment: @Steve Yes, I mean zooming the page

Answer (score 1):

hi donot use px with width or other thing use % in width for example

```
 .cotainer{width : 50% ; margin : 0 auto }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
```

You can use like this for setting different css for different kind of screen resolution

Answer (score 0):

Because you have place a fixed width of 960px on your container it won't collapse.  You could use a percentage like

```
.container{
    width : 80% ;
    margin : 0 auto;
}
```

That way the carousel will be 80% the size of the screen.  It's also worth taking a look at Twitter Bootstrap if you haven't already.  It has a built in carousel that you can use which will be responsive.

[Twitter Bootstrap Carousel](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#carousel)

Comment: I tried, but it doesn't help, see fiddle I embedded. It still jumps.
Also, I try to stray away from frameworks because I stand by the rule that you should first know how to do it yourself barebones to understand things better :)

Answer (score 0):

i put in two lines into your .disc ul class. Not sure if this is what you are looking for:

```
.discs ul {
    margin: 0;
    height:106px; /*put whatever height you want */
    overflow:hidden;
}
```